# Inflating an Android layout from a resource that's packed in a JAR

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I'm building a library for an Android project, it contains a View subclass that's inflating a layout from XML. I export it to a JAR (Right click on project -> Export -> Tick classes and resources) and I've verified that the classes, XML resource and dependent JAR libraries are all in there.

My view's constructor is this:

```
MyView(Context aContext, AttributeSet aAttrs)
```

The view is added via XML. The context there is the project the library is included from, so `aContext.getPackageName()` returns the package of the final project.

To find the XML of my view to inflate it, I do this:

```
int layout_id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("name_of_layout", "layout", context.getPackageName());
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(layout_id, this, true);
```

That doesn't work, because the `context.getPackageName()` returns the package name of the final project and the resources are in the JAR. I've tried changing it to the package name of the library project. That did not work. The strange thing is, the class `MyView` is inside the JAR and I `import` the JAR package name in the final project to make use of the class.

To make things complicated, I have 2 projects: one Android library project that includes the exported JAR, and one project that uses what's in the JAR. The JAR library, library project that includes the JAR, and the final project that uses what's in the JAR all have different package names.

How do I find the right resource ID of my layout?

Which `Context` should I use, and which package name? Can I set this package name inside the JAR regardless of the library or project it's referenced from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I export it to a JAR (Right click on project -> Export -> Tick classes and resources) and I've verified that the classes, XML resource and dependent JAR libraries are all in there.

The XML resource files will be useless there. Android does not use Java JAR resources.

I'm not even sure that the dependent JARs will work, though I won't rule that out.

You need to treat this as an ordinary Android library project that other projects depend upon, or move to Gradle/Android Studio and package it as an AAR (which *does* include Android resources).

Or, get rid of the resources (e.g., convert the layout code into corresponding Java code).

Comment: I have .aar library and i have successfully import but there is a MapView class layout which is programmatically written when i add it to the xml inlcude its give error ndroid.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.tomtom.pnd.maplib.MapView

Comment: @justchill: I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you can provide a [mcve]. That would include the complete Java stack trace, plus the layout that is triggering the crash.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pack xml or drawable resources in a jar file and then use them from another project.
You have two options in front of you,
1. Just use a normal Android library project instead of the jar file
2. Move to a gradle based build/Android Studio and create a *.aar file for the library. This is a new type that contains the classes and all the resources from your library project.